# how can i sum a columns in DataFrame with each date in time series data

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

## Here's the example

'''

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Country': ['United States', 'China', 'Italy', 'spain'],
                   '2020-01-01' : [0, 2, 1, 0]
                   '2020-01-02' : [1, 0, 1, 2]
                   '2020-01-03' : [0, 3, 2, 0]
df
```

'''

i want to sum the value of columns by date so that next columns has the added value.__         which means 2020-01-02 has a new added value of (2020-01-01+2020-01-02) and so on..

Comment: Try df.cumsum(axis=1)

Comment: Thank you. @YOBEN_S

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert `Country` column to index by [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) and use [`DataFrame.cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.cumsum.html) per rows by `axis=1`:

```
df = df.set_index('Country').cumsum(axis=1)
print (df)
               2020-01-01  2020-01-02  2020-01-03
Country                                          
United States           0           1           1
China                   2           2           5
Italy                   1           2           4
spain                   0           2           2
```

Or select all columns without first by [`DataFrame.iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) before `cumsum`:

```
df.iloc[:, 1:] = df.iloc[:, 1:].cumsum(axis=1)
print (df)
         Country  2020-01-01  2020-01-02  2020-01-03
0  United States           0           1           1
1          China           2           2           5
2          Italy           1           2           4
3          spain           0           2           2
```